# nuxt and electron - cannot get /

Tags: vue.js, electron, nuxt.js

I've posted an issue https://github.com/nuxt-community/electron-template/issues/27 but maybe here it will be more efficient

I've used `nuxt-community/electron-template` template, generated the app.

In development mode everything works ok. But If I build the app I get `Cannot GET /`.

Commands:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=DEV electron .",
    "dev:web": "cross-env NODE_ENV=DEV BUILD_TARGET=web  nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build && electron-builder",
    "build:web": "cross-env nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env nuxt build && nuxt start"
  },
```

It is strange that template doesn't work out of the box. How to properly configure electron and nuxt to work together?

Comment: Any updates? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and had no problems

1) create a folder called template

D:\Coding\template

2) Download electron-template-master.zip from github - https://github.com/nuxt-community/electron-template

3) Copy contents of ZIP (template folder, LICENSE, META, Readme) to D:\coding\template

4) mkdir projects

D:\Coding\projects

5) cd projects

6) npm install vue-cli

7) vue init D:\Coding\template project

8) cd project

9) npm install

10) npm run build

[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with nuxt, that works with own node server

Comment: Not understanding your comment. Explain?

Comment: This does not anwser the question